# Regular Expressions and ID's in R

Tags: r, regex

Say I have an example of data like this:

```r
ID      Text
23      Patient has a probable chance of diabetes
78      He had to go to the doctor today
92      He mentioned possible diabetes
83      Patient likely has diabetes
45      She told us about her family history
```

I want to find the texts where it says "probable" or "possible" diabetes, but I want to return the list of ID's and their matching text where those are found. In this case, I want to return a dataset of:

```r
ID     Text
23      Patient has a probable chance of diabetes
92      He mentioned possible diabetes
```

Comment: Please do add what you tried?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything yet. I am newer to R and usually use SAS for regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df  %>%  filter(str_detect(Text, "possible|probable"))

#> A tibble: 2 x 2
#>     ID Text                                     
#>  <dbl> <chr>                                    
#>1    23 Patient has a probable chance of diabetes
#>2    92 He mentioned possible diabetes
```

#### data

```
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(
~ID, ~Text,
23, "Patient has a probable chance of diabetes",
78, "He had to go to the doctor today",
92, "He mentioned possible diabetes",
83, "Patient likely has diabetes",
45, "She told us about her family history")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
^.*?(?:probable|possible).*
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^`** - Represents start of the line.
- **`.*?`** - Matches everything except new-line **lazily** zero or more times.
- **`(?:probable|possible)`** - Represents a non-capturing group matching either the word `probable` or `possible`.
- **`.*`** - Matches  everything except new-line **greedily** zero or more times.

---

[image]

#### Regex Demo

Comment: why the `\d+`? There are no digits in the above example

Comment: The text appears in the question to be white space separated lines. In reality in R, we know they are probably in a data frame as two separate columns. So I think this would be right in a TSV file or something, but not in an R data frame.

Comment: Which is a completely different column. The columns are different.

Comment: Take a note of the two other solutions given.

Answer (score 1):

With Base R:

```r
df = read.table(text="ID      Text
23      'Patient has a probable chance of diabetes'
                78      'He had to go to the doctor today'
                92      'He mentioned possible diabetes'
                83      'Patient likely has diabetes'
                45      'She told us about her family history'", header = TRUE)

df[(grep('possible|probable', df$Text)), ]
#>   ID                                      Text
#> 1 23 Patient has a probable chance of diabetes
#> 3 92            He mentioned possible diabetes
```